# DrawLine method provides higher quality than DrawLines method

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

In my aplication I need to plot an equation. The plotted equation will be composed of many small linear lines. When I plot it using the DrawLine method inside a for I get higher quality than when using the DrawLines method.

```
Graphics canvas = pnlCanvas.CreateGraphics();
canvas.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

//High Quality
for (int i = 0; i < plot_points.Length - 1; i++)
{
    canvas.DrawLine(penKat, plot_points[i], plot_points[i + 1]);
}

//Low Quality
canvas.DrawLines(penKat, plot_points);
```

I need to plot it using the DrawLines method because of some issues. Is there a way to get high quality using that method?

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  Use the graphic object from pnlCanvas's paint event.  Your pen information would be nice to have.  Consider using StartCap and EndCaps for your pen to make the DrawLine example more compatible with the DrawLines example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 penKat.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
 penKat.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
 penKat.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
```

MiterLimit might help, if your lines are thicker than a few pixels..

**Edit:**
For crisp joins you may want to experiment with other LineJoin values:

```
 penKat.LineJoin = LineJoin.MiterClipped;
 penKat.MiterLimit = 1.5f;
```

Or

```
 penKat.LineJoin = LineJoin.Miter;
 penKat.MiterLimit = 1.5f;
```

Do try out other MiteLimit values until you're happy!
Or post an example image with the two versions..

For stroke widths of 2-4 pixels the difference between the LineJoins will not be very visible. This changes **dramatically** with growing stroke widths; so remember this property for those thicker lines!

Comment: Nice. That made it a little better

Comment: How thick are the lines? the Pen definition might really help.. DrawLines should deliver at least the same quality as several DrawLine calls. And in the case of tranparency it is obligatory!

Comment: The lines are 3 pixels thick. Your code fixed the starting and ending point of the lines. I can't vote you up because I haven't enough reputation XD

Comment: Can you describe the remaining problems?

Comment: EndCap and StartCap works great. Whatever I use on LineJoin doeasn't change the outcome though but it's ok, looks fine like this too. Thanks!